# Cross Database Query in Azure SQL Database Performance

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have installed `Sql Server 2012` on my virtual machine. I am looking to migrate `SQL Server` database to `Azure database`. I have three database. In that I have multiple table. Suppose I have `Database1.table1 ... ,Database2.table1 ... ,Database3.table1 ....` and in that I have some tables and stored procedures which use cross db queries to get result.

When I try to migrate to Azure database I found that it does not support Cross query. To achieve this I need give the external table reference in parent table. I followed these links

https://sqldusty.com/2017/05/30/setting-up-cross-database-queries-in-azure-sql-database/

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/cross-database-queries-in-azure-sql/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-getting-started-vertical

Here I want to know that,

> Is it store same data in **parent** as well as in **external
>   referenced** table?

and

> How does it affects on performance?(Means I have millions of records in db2.table1 and I am joining db1.table1 on primary key column with where clause.)

Comment: Have you considered hosting them in the same database but different schemes?  Manages Instance is now in preview and it supports cross-database queries so you could look at that.

Comment: I too would go with managed instances ,if you need more on premises like experience'

Comment: @wBob thanks for reply. Yeah I have hosted in same `Database` but with different schema name

Comment: @TheGameiswar Will go through the documentation. Thanks

Comment: @TheGameiswar I chacked Managed instances and decided to go to Azure Sql database instead. I have one question can you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50289411/azure-cross-database-queries?