# Azure cross database queries,External resources, External tables

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I am migrating all my **VM** `Sql Server 2012` database to **Azure Sql Database**. In my current structure I am using **cross database** queries to fetch data from different database tables.

I have created external table to my parent table using below query

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'yourPassword';  

CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL yourServeradminlogin  
WITH IDENTITY = 'yourServeradminlogin',  
SECRET = 'yourPassword';  

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE RefmyDemoDB2  
WITH  
(  
    TYPE=RDBMS,  
    LOCATION='testdbdemoserver.database.windows.net',  
    DATABASE_NAME='myDemoDB2',  
    CREDENTIAL= yourServeradminlogin  
);  
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[Department](  
    [DeptId] [int] NOT NULL,  
    [Name] [varchar](50) NULL  
)  
WITH  
(  
    DATA_SOURCE = RefmyDemoDB2  
);  


/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/  
SELECT *  
  FROM [dbo].[Employee] E  
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[Department] D  
  ON E.DeptId = D.DeptId
```

I referred this link https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/cross-database-queries-in-azure-sql/

But when I create external table it doesn't shows table in **external table** folder like shown in below image.
[image]

In my case it directly showing in **Tables** folder.

> Anyone knows why I don't see **Department** table in `External Tables` folder? How can I add such tables in `External Tables` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

External tables are available in Azure SQL only to support a feature called "Elastic Queries", that may solve your problem:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-overview

If this is not enough for you, and you really need full cross-database query support, you have to use an Azure SQL Managed Instance:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance

which seems to be exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have `Azure Sql`. I followed all steps mentions in link but still tables not showing in `external tables` folder.

Comment: I have `SQL Server Management Studio 2012` locally installed on my machine. I use it to connect to `Azure Sql Server`. And it shows list of `database` created on `Azure Sql Server`

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio 2012 is not aware of external table existence. You need to update to SQL Server Management Studio 2016 or 2017. Here's the link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yeah yesterday I have installed `2017` and now it is showing me everything.